# WPF ListBox SelectionChanged event

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a problem with listbox. When in my program I click on one ListBoxItem, I want to change/open the window and preorder it before. But the problem is that it firstly fires the event and then it changes selection. Code:

```
private void LB_Playlist_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (LB_Playlist.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            try
            {
                List<string> _tempList = new List<string>();
                File_Load_List(LB_Playlist.SelectedItem.ToString(), _tempList);
                LoadListIntoBox(_tempList);
                G_SongList.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                AnimationMove(G_Playlist, G_Playlist.Margin, new Thickness(-264, 0, 0, 0), AnimationDuration, true);
                AnimationMove(G_SongList, new Thickness(264, 0, 0, 0), new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0), AnimationDuration, false);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

When I tried it with 
    MessageBox.Show(LB_Playlist.SelectedIndex.ToString());
It was working, selection was changing but the message was showing. Is there any way to change it?

Answer (score 6):

The `SelectionChangedEventArgs` will contain which item was deselected and which item was selected. Use `e.AddedItems` to get the newly selected items. e.g.

```
var addedItems = e.AddedItems;
if(addedItems.Count > 0)
{
    var selectedItem = addedItems[0];
    File_Load_List(selectedItem.ToString(), _tempList);
}
```

This way you do not need to worry about whether the event is raised before or after the control being updated, but you do know the event args contain the correct information.

Comment: It isn't working right. The selection does change but not the way it should. It gets the last selection not the new one if I understood working right.

Answer (score 0):

With the MessageBox call, you likely allowed the UI to update, and change the selection before your code executed.

You should be able to remove the sleep, and use

File_Load_List(LB_Playlist.SelectedItem.Content.ToString(), _tempList);

Comment: Content doesn't exist.

Answer (score -3):

Solved. Just added Thread.Sleep(70); before try&catch.

Comment: I would advise against doing this, as it is still indeterminate behavior. Will 70ms be enough of a delay on the slowest of computers?

Comment: I have no clue. Works fine on my fast computer. I think it will cause It still must wait 70ms which are enough to get current selection. Still waiting for help.

Comment: Well, it's outrageous but it works. I'm using it until I get a better solution.